# Very confused about JavaScript scopes

Tags: javascript

Below is a greatly simplified snippet of code derived from a SlickGrid sample:

**model.js:**

```
(function($) {
    function RemoteModel() {
        var someArr=[0];
        var someVar=0;
        var onDataLoadedSuccess = new Slick.Event();

        function ensureData(from, to) {
            h_request = setTimeout(function() {
                req = $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    context: this,
                    success: function(resp) {
                        onSuccess();
                    }
                });
            }, 3000);
        }

        function onSuccess() {
            someVar=someVar+100;
            someArr[0]=someArr[0]+100;
            console.log(someVar + " " + someArr[0]); // yes values are changing properly for both !

            onDataLoadedSuccess.notify({ from: from, to: to });
        }

        return {
            "someArr": someArr,
            "someVar": someVar,
            "onDataLoadedSuccess": onDataLoadedSuccess,
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**main.js:**

```
var loader=new RemoteModel();
var grid=new Slick.Grid("#wlGrid", loader.data, columns, options);

grid.onViewportChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    var vp = grid.getViewport();
    loader.ensureData(vp.top, vp.bottom);
});

loader.onDataLoadedSuccess.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    // someVar is always 0 :( ! someArr[0] is changing fine .. why ???
    console.log(loader.someVar + " " + loader.someArr[0]); 
});
```

So an event on the grid (`onViewportChanged`) is calling `ensureData` on the model, which 
increments both `someVar` and `someArr[0]`, both of which are exposed by the return value 
of `RemoteModel`.

After incrementing the event, `onDataLoadedSuccess` is triggered by the model, however 
within that event only the value of `loader.someArr[0]` has changed.

why is the value of `someVar` in `onDataLoadedSuccess` always zero? Is that a scope issue?
And why is the value of `someArr[0]` changing fine?

How can I properly read the value of `someVar` in `onDataLoadedSuccess`?

Comment: OK I think I understand what's going on now, thanks everyone !

But how do I make someVar work? I need to keep the constructor returning an object (because there are a quite a few methods there), but I still want o allow thisVar to be accessable from ensureData, onSuccess, and onDataLoadedSuccess ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RemoteModel` function has local variables for `someVar` and `someArr`. These are also returned as the object properties when `loader` is created. The difference is that the value of the number for `someVar` is effectively copied into `loader` when it is created.

The array is copied into `someArr` as well, but the copy is by reference. Thus you have two things pointing to the same array. When the event executes, it updates the local variable and the local array. `loader` points to the same array, so you see `someArr[0]` change, but it does not "point to" the number, so when the local `someArr` is changed the `loader` value is not.

**Edit to address the comment**

One option is to define your returned object first and then have your private functions reference it. This could be limited to numbers or apply to all public members; I would do the latter for clarity. With this approach, only the class needs to change, not the code calling it.

```
function RemoteModel() {
    var ret = {
        "someArr": [0],
        "someVar": 0,
        "onDataLoadedSuccess": new Slick.Event()
    };        

    function onSuccess() {
        ret.someVar=ret.someVar+100;
        // ...
    }

    return ret;
    // ...
```

A second option is to create a `getSomeVar` method that is in your returned object so that outside the class you do `loader.getSomeVar()` instead of just `loader.someVar`. (And you could create a `setSomeVar(newValue)` if it needs to be externally settable.

```
function RemoteModel() {
    var someVar=0;
    // ...

    function getSomeVar() {
        return someVar;
    }

    return {
        "someArr": someArr,
        "getSomeVar": getSomeVar,
        "onDataLoadedSuccess": onDataLoadedSuccess,
    };
}
```

and then:

```
loader.onDataLoadedSuccess.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    console.log(loader.getSomeVar() + " " + loader.someArr[0]); 
});
```

Comment: great thank you very much !
see my comment on the post, now that I understand my issue, can you help solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you created a model, you returned this to `loader`:

```
return {
  "someArr": someArr,
  "someVar": someVar,
  "onDataLoadedSuccess": onDataLoadedSuccess,
}
```

`loader.someArr` is pointing to the same array pointed by `someArr` in the closure. `someVar`, however, is a property with a value of 0, *copied* from `someVar` in the closure.

When assigning a variable or object property with an object (including arrays), you are referencing to that object. Thus, `loader.someArr` is pointing to the same array pointed by `someArr` in the closure. Changes can be done via both `someArr` and `loader.someArr` since they point to the same array.

But in the case of `someVar`, you assigned `loader.someVar` from `someVar`. Since `0` is a primitive value, the value is *copied* from `someVar` to `loader.someVar`. Thus, `someVar` and `loader.someVar` don't point to the same thing. Modifying `someVar` does not modify `loader.someVar` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers and other non-object primitives get returned by value, not by reference:

```
    return {
        "someArr": someArr, // <-- object
        "someVar": someVar, // <-- number
        "onDataLoadedSuccess": onDataLoadedSuccess,
    };
```

`someArr` is an object (array), which will be returned by reference. However `someVar` is just a simple number. Thereby you're returning a value.

Instead of returning an object in your `RemoteModel` you should use `RemoteModel` as a proper constructor:

```
    this.someArr=[0];
    this.someVar=0;
    this.onDataLoadedSuccess = new Slick.Event();

    /* move other functions into the prototype, get rid of the return */
```

If you're not familiar with using a function as a constructor see [Working with Objects on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirect=no#Using_a_constructor_function).

Comment: great thank you very much !
see my comment on the post, now that I understand my issue, can you help solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because how javascript is handling the values.

```
(function($) {
    function RemoteModel() {
        this.someArr=[0];
        this.someVar=0;
        this.onDataLoadedSuccess = new Slick.Event();

        var _this = this;

        function ensureData(from, to) {
            h_request = setTimeout(function() {
                req = $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    context: this,
                    success: function(resp) {
                        onSuccess();
                    }
                });
            }, 3000);
        }

        function onSuccess() {
            _this.someVar=_this.someVar+100;
            _this.someArr[0]=_this.someArr[0]+100;
            console.log(_this.someVar + " " + _this.someArr[0]); // yes values are changing properly for both !

            _this.onDataLoadedSuccess.notify({ from: from, to: to });
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: great thank you very much !
see my comment on the post, now that I understand my issue, can you help solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because at the Moment you return

```
{
        "someArr": someArr,
        "someVar": someVar,
        "onDataLoadedSuccess": onDataLoadedSuccess,
};
```

`someVar` is `0`.

`someVar` holds a `String`, a primitive type.

`someArr` references an `Array` a non Primitive type.

Strings *(and other **primitive types**)*
are passed **by value**, Arrays *(and other **non-primitive types**)* by **reference**. *More specific: the variables reference to the Object gets passed by value (when passed the new var holds a copy of the reference)*

So what you return is a "copy" of your String